# When Would My Medicare Part B Coverage Begin?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, medicare

I am over 65 and currently have Medicare Part A coverage, and am under my husband's GHP. He is leaving his job on 9/11/2020, at which time I will no longer be insured. If I sign up for Medicare Part B online today, 8/30/20, or tomorrow 8/31/20, what day would my Part B coverage begin?

Comment: How old are you?

Comment: I'll be 72 in November.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, Medicare coverage starts effective with the *beginning* of the month in which the enrollee turns 65, with, of course, the initial application for Medicare coverage having been made about three months previously. I believe that in cases such as that of the OP, coverage starts at the beginning of the month in which the other insurance terminates, and so coverage will begin 9/1/2020.